# Can I mock a message-enricher in mule unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, mule

I have a message-enricher , inside that I have a call to data base to get sequence value. Here is the component of my flow

```
<enricher doc:name="Enrich Flow Variable">
            <db:select config-ref="LocalhostPostgres" doc:name="Database">
                <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[Select (nextval('batch_id_seq'))]]></db:parameterized-query>

            </db:select>
            <enrich source="#[payload[0].nextval]" target="#[flowVars.flow_batch_id]" />
            <enrich source="#['INPUT_CSV']" target="#[flowVars.flow_source_name]" />
        </enricher>
```

what I want,, in my unit testing I want to mock it so that I can pass constant values to my flow_batch_id.
Is there any way to do it?. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't mock the enricher. Instead I would mock the db:select to return a sample result. You can either mock the db:select operation, or move the db:select to a sub-flow/private flow and mock that instead. Take a look at the munit mock documentation: https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/v/1.1.1/mock-message-processor

Comment: Hi,,thank u. i am able to mock the query but gets null value. Could you please tell me, how to pass some value to flow_batch_id?.